# pyenv-virtualenv python version does not change on env activation

Tags: python, zsh, pyenv, pyenv-virtualenv

I've got some problems with activating virtual environments using pyenv-virtualenv. When I activate an environment with pyenv, it looks like it worked. However the python version has not changed. The only way to activate it is to manually run the activation script in the corresponding folder:

```
/usr/bin/python
➜  ~ pyenv activate test_env 
pyenv-virtualenv: prompt changing will be removed from future release. configure `export PYENV_VIRTUALENV_DISABLE_PROMPT=1' to simulate the behavior.
(test_env) ➜  ~ which python
/usr/bin/python
(test_env) ➜  ~ source .pyenv/versions/test_env/bin/activate
(test_env) ➜  ~ which python
/Users/tom/.pyenv/versions/3.9.6/envs/test_env/bin/python
(test_env) ➜  ~
```

I added these two lines to my `.zshrc`:

```
eval "$(pyenv init -)"
eval "$(pyenv virtualenv-init -)"
```

I'm using zsh with Oh My Zsh on macOS 11.6 on an M1 MacBook Pro.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Pyenv 2.0+, also add `eval "$(pyenv init --path)"` to `.zprofile` and make sure your Terminal runs Zsh as a login shell.

(See installation instructions for Zsh in MacOS in https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv#readme)

Comment: This changed nothing on my machine

Comment: Is `<pyenv root>/shims` in your `PATH`? Does it even exist? How did you create the env?